Azure SQL Managed Instance - Private Link to one database connection
Is there a way to connect via Azure Private Link (PL) to Azure SQL Managed Instance (MI SQL) to one (chosen) database?
I have followed many tutorial (eg: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/private-endpoints-for-azure-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/3782015) for creating PL and connecting to Azure MI SQL but none of them explain in particular connection to one database only.
Customer will be given private link (pointing do MI SQL server in Private DNS Zone), and he has this own user and password to this database.
Is this connection narrowed by using connection string with specified database in it (and created before PL)?
Can I restrict user in database - will it be enough?
Regards

By creating a database-level user and granting permissions only to the specific database, you restrict the customer's access to that single database. The customer will not have access to other databases on the managed instance.

Tahnk you for answer. I have done this as well.


Is there a way to connect via Azure Private Link (PL) to Azure SQL Managed Instance (MI SQL) to one (chosen) database?

There is a way to connect Azure SQL Managed Instance through private link but it's not possible to connect with a database. As per this document, private access to the database is allowed through virtual networks like Virtual network firewall and Private Link but it's not applicable for SQL Managed Instance.
Below are the steps which allow private access to the database from Private Link:

Open SQL Server which is already created and go to Networking under Security and click on Private access and select the Private endpoint, if it is not created then create a new Private endpoint. Click on Approve if it is not Auto-approved.


Open the respected Private endpoint and open Network interface as shown below.


Note the IP address which is shown in the Network interface as shown below and use that IP address at the Azure SQL Server networking to access the database.



Open this document for more information on Private Link.
